# Более оптимальное решение для проверки доступа пользователя к ресурсу

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

Допустим имеется решение веб приложения для внутренней работы компании. С проектами Core, MVC. В MVC для регистрации и авторизации используется Identity.

Имеются две базы: первая под Identity, вторая под ресурсы компании. Во второй имеется таблица хранящая данные о доступах пользователя к компании, в которой UserId соответствует пользователю из базы Identity.

В Core в каждом сервисе бизнес логики проверяется проверка имеет ли пользователь доступ к ресурсу, т.е например в ICompanyService проверяется имеет ли доступ пользователь к компании, в ICompanyCommandService проверяется имеет ли доступ пользователь к данной команде сервиса. И так выходит, что в каждый метод приходится добавлять UserId, взятый из Identity и прокидывать его по методам для проверки доступа. Что мне кажется не удобным.

Имеется ли более удобное решение?

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно попробовать перейти на авторизацию по [JWT-токену](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php).

Техника следующая: на сервере хранится закрытый ключ. Когда пользователь вводит свои логин и пароль сервер возвращает ему генерированный токен, подписаный при помощи этого закрытого ключа. Затем, пользователь делает запросы к API посылая этот токен (в заголовке, например).

Сам токен представляет собой *контейнер* в котором можно хранить различные параметры, включая необходимые права пользователя. Так как токен подписан, вам не нужно проверять данные внутри него. Таким образом можно избавится от постоянных проверок в базе. Инфраструктура asp.net поддерживает работу с этими ключами через схему проверки подлинности [JWT Bearer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

- [Пять простых шагов для понимания JSON Web Tokens](https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/)

Comment: возможно я неверно вопрос понял, но, кмк, автор спрашивает о пользк проверок  полномочий юзера для конкретных операций в коде сервисов. `т.е например в ICompanyService проверяется имеет ли доступ пользователь к компании, в ICompanyCommandService проверяется имеет ли доступ пользователь к данной команде сервиса`

Comment: то есть ваш ответ сам по себе хороший, но не имеет связи с вопросом. Вы избавляетесь от запроса в БД, но не избавляетесь от самих проверок в коде сервиса. Под сервисом я тут понимаю конкретный класс бинес логики, а не все приложение.

Comment: @tym32167 Правильно поняли. Вы в момент авторизации получаете все разрешения. В коде можно использовать стандартные атрибуты авторизации вроде Authorize и политики. Это поддерживается в том числе.

Comment: я знаю как рвботает JWT, я про то, что у автора походу многослойная арзитеутура, он из своих контроллеров вызывает методы классов-сервисов, и уже в классах сервисах проверяет наличие прав юзера на конкретные операции. Но это чтсто мое предположение.

Comment: @tym32167 ну... возможно. В любом случае голд-хаммера покрывающего 100% кейсов тут нет. Придется где-то и проверки делать :-)

Comment: я к тому, что похоже вопрос не в том, какой способ аутентификации/авторизации использовать , а больше в том, как оптимально защитить свои операции на уровне бизнес логики.

Comment: @tym32167 попробовал обновить ответ, но без реального кода только теоретические рассуждения получаются. Возможно, автору подойдет вариант, когда пользователю фабрика сразу выплюнет граф `ICompanyService - ICompanyCommandService` в котором будут установлены все разрешенные компании и операции. Но это все теоретическая теория

Comment: Да, мне нужно как более оптимально совершать проверки доступа пользователя к запрашиваемому ресурсу в бизнес слое. И можно ссылку или подробнее про граф.

Comment: @faketogosamogo здесь нет особого трюка. Если у вас цель сократить количество выборок данных в коде то вариант тут простой — выбрать их сразу все. Сделайте фабрику (или абстрактную фабрику) которая вам по пользователю сразу будет возвращать нужные вам сервисы в которых уже заполнены списки сущностей, к которым есть у пользователя доступ. Таким образом у вас будет модель, при которой пользователь будет работать уже с доступными данными и можно будет облегчить сигнатуры и убрать в этих сервисах проверки на пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!